# Any Ideas What 十二本の腕 Means?

Tags: counters, song-lyrics

In Monkey Majik's song "Change" they say "Time to Party 十二本の腕", what does 十二本の腕 means? Isn't it just 12, counter for long objects, arms? Why would this be applicable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are looking for some deep meaning I cannot think of, I would say it is applicable because the song is played by 6 guys --- 4 from Monkey Majik and 2 from the Yoshida Brothers.  That is 12 arms all together instead of saying "the 6 of us".